# Trigger Jenkins job when pushing to a particular git branch

Tags: git, jenkins

I am using jenkins with the GitHub Plugin for my project. I would like to create a job that only triggers the job when a push is made to a branch called `staging`

I have a webhook set up on github which is sent with "just the push event". On the jenkins job, I have it set up to "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub".

My issue is that the job is triggered anytime a push is made to any branch, and I would like it to only occur for pushes to the staging branch. Is there a configuration for doing so? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Manage Jenkins -->Manage Plugins-->Installed tab and make sure you have `Git Plugin` installed. If not, click the `Available` tab to install it.
2. In your job configuration,under the `Source Code Management` section, choose `Git` and put ***/staging** in the `Branch Specifier` field.

[image]