# Have Jenkins pipeline been triggered when pushing commits to a different branch

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This question is different from [Trigger Jenkins job when pushing to a particular git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440370/trigger-jenkins-job-when-pushing-to-a-particular-git-branch).

I am not triggering a job, I want to trigger a pipeline from commits to a non-master branch. How can I achieve that?

A more generic question is can I can setup the pipeline trigger based on a tag name with a regular expression?

Answer (score 2):

Place a [`Jenkinsfile`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) in all branches that you want to build and use the [Multi-Branch Project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multi-Branch+Project+Plugin) and [GitHub Organization Folder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Organization+Folder+Plugin) plugins to scan all branches of a Github org (Bitbucket and IIRC Gitlab are also supported).

If you fear that you have to duplicate your pipeline code over and over again, there's the [Workflow Global Library](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/jenkins-workflow-using-global-library-implement-re-usable-function-call-secured-http-endpoint), which allows to centralize common functionality. I'm using this to simplify my [`Jenkinsfile`](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/site-chefcitypo3org/blob/develop/Jenkinsfile) to the following lines:

```
def pipe = new org.typo3.chefci.v1.Pipeline()
pipe.execute()
```

and call the [global library](https://github.com/TYPO3-infrastructure/jenkins-pipeline-global-library-chefci/tree/master/src/org/typo3/chefci/v1), where the pipeline is configured at a single place.